# How to implement Inapp Purchase for multiple products?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, in-app-purchase

I want to implement Inapp purchase for multiple products in my app.

Do I need to register All the products at iTunes? and is the code procedure is same for multiple as for single product?

I don't know what is the requirement of restore button in Inapp.

If anyone having tutorial or code for multiple product inApp then please provide.

Thanks

Comment: Introduction to In-App Purchases in iOS 6 [Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register all your product in iTunes store for multiple InApp purchase.

**What is the requirement of restore button in Inapp ?**

If user accidentally deleted the app from their device. If he/she again downloaded or installed the App. They won't get the previously purchased items, then he/she should again purchase them for using it. In that case you need to provide an option for restoring the already purchased items.

This is a nice [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases)

Comment: Introduction to In-App Purchases in iOS 6 [Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial).

Comment: @Sudhakar: I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: Raywenderlich released in-App Purchases new tutorial for ios 6.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read this. You will get all your answers [InApp Purchase](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases)

Comment: Introduction to In-App Purchases in iOS 6 [Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial).

Comment: @Sudhakar yes, but it is not clear from the question that on which ios questioner is working. So I gave url for ios5 which itself contains reference for ios6